# Android Gradle: signingConfig.name must not be null

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

After updating Gradle Wrapper to 5.6.4 and Gradle Plugin to 3.6.0, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: signingConfig.name must not be null
```

My configuration looks like this:

root:

```
ext {
    Properties localProps = new Properties()
    localProps.load(rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

    mySigningConfigs = [
            debug  : SigningConfig.newInstance([
                    keyAlias     : "${localProps['keyAlias']}",
                    keyPassword  : "${localProps['keyPassword']}",
                    storeFile    : file('carrierKeystore.jks'),
                    storePassword: "${localProps['storePassword']}"
            ]),
            release: SigningConfig.newInstance([
                    keyAlias     : "${localProps['keyAlias']}",
                    keyPassword  : "${localProps['keyPassword']}",
                    storeFile    : file('carrierKeystore.jks'),
                    storePassword: "${localProps['storePassword']}"
            ])
    ]
}
```

module:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig mySigningConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig mySigningConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

It worked great before, but not it's always saying `name` is null. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: did you have any progress ? I'm facing the exact same issue

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem

move the lines

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig mySigningConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig mySigningConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

to

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            mySigningConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            mySigningConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

and put the signingConfigs block at the top of the android block

i.e

```
android {
  signingConfigs {
    ...
  }

  defaultConfigs {
    ...
  }

  buildTypes {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60431816/3559908) didn't help. But moving the `signingConfigs` from the `ext` section (probably of your root gradle file) directly to the `android` block of the module gradle worked. So try the following:

**Within the `android` block add**

```java
signingConfigs {
        // optional read your properties with the signingConfig data
        // but keep in mind that you may have to adapt your file paths
        release {
            keyAlias "<keyAliasValue>"
            keyPassword "<keyPasswordValue>"
            storeFile file('<keyStoreFileName>')
            storePassword "<keyStorePasswordValue>"
        }
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

**Within the `buildTypes` -> `release` section you can keep your assignment of the concrete `signingConfig`**

```java
buildTypes {

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    .
    .
    .
```

**Then you may have to adapt your paths (localProps and store file) from**

```
rootProject.file('local.properties')
storeFile file('carrierKeystore.jks')
```

**to**

```
// adapt to new path of the files 
rootProject.file('../local.properties')
storeFile file('../carrierKeystore.jks')
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be a signingConfigs block in your andorid block.
like this

```
 signingConfigs {
    release {
        appSigningConfigs.release
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    ...
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```